# TestNG listeners, how to pass class name?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have my listener override like this :

```
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("Test: " + getTestMethodName(result) + " failure");
        String methodName=result.getName().toString().trim();
        String className = result.getClass().toString().trim();
        takeScreenShot(methodName, className);

    }

    public void takeScreenShot(String methodName, String className) {
    driver=className.getDriver();  //it wont work this way :(
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(methodName+".png"));

}
```

lets say my class is TestClass, and there is method getDriver that returns driver, but:

**driver=className.getDriver();**

how to pass this className variable ? 
i dont want to make separate listeners for each class, and String className is not WebDriver type

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void takeScreenShot(ITestResult itr) {
    YourClass currentClass = (YourClass) itr.getInstance();
    WebDriver driver = currentClass.getDriver();

    // ...
```

Comment: Ok but how to do this if I dont know exact YourClass name ?Can I  get this name somehow as a variable

Comment: public static WebDriver getDriver() {
  return driver;
 }

this is how my getDriver method looks like, and when I do it your way it says The method getDriver is undefined for the type Class. ClassName ? Should i use this or just Class type for variable ?

Comment: "YouClass" is the name of that Class where is your getDriver method. So in your case: "className".

Comment: still I can pass only one class, I would like to do it even if I dont know class name (as a variable), i dont want to do this 10x times for 10 classes

Answer (score 0):

You can work on this, in your class you need to set driver attribute and then you can use this attribute in Listener class for Example

testClass.java

```
@BeforeClass
public void setDriver(ITestContext context){
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  context.setAttribute("WedDeiver", driver);
}
@Test
public void t1(){
// your code
}
```

Listner.java

```
WebDriver driver = null;
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    ITestContext context = result.getTestContext();
    driver = (RemoteWebDriver) context.getAttribute("WebDriver");
    // your code
}
```

You can use above driver from any class now, the only thing is you need to set the driver attribute value in you test class